# Following-sibling ось с аругментами

Tags: xpath, javascript

Объясните как работает ось **following-sibling::A/B** с аргументами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то аргументов у "осей" нету. Пусть есть такой xml:

```
<bookstore>

 <book>
   <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
   <price>29.99</price>
   <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
 </book>

 <book>
   <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
   <price>39.95</price>
   <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
 </book>

</bookstore>
```

Сначала мы находим какой-то элемент, например, название "Learning XML":

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]
```

а теперь хотим узнать цену этой книги. Цена - элемент из следующих (following-sibling), получится так:

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]/following-sibling::price
```

или непосредственно цена:

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]/following-sibling::price/text()
```

или автор:

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]/following-sibling::author/text()
```

Другие оси работают аналогично, например, название предыдущих (если их несколько) книг:

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]/ancestor::book/preceding-sibling::book/title/text()
```

Нашли определенный title, поднялись на уровень книг, получили все предыдущие книги, узнали у них название.

Или цена предыдущей (одной) книги:

```
//title[.="Learning XML"]/ancestor::book/preceding-sibling::book[1]/price/text()
```

Comment: тестить xpath можно [здесь](http://www.xpathtester.com/) или [здесь](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm)

Comment: спасибо за ссылки и инфу. PS интересно почему их назвали Оси

Comment: ну можно так объяснить: дефолтная ось - дети, т.е. каждый шаг идет внутрь дерева. а другое движение по дереву - не вглубь - идет по другим осям...  
ЗЫ награждать не надо, если ответ устраивает полностью достаточно галки для принятия. опционально можно добавить палец вверх. ваша карма при этом не расходуется.